# Is it possible to use CAM_GPIO0 for image sensor clock signal?

Tags: camera

I am working with a freelancer who designed an IMX327 MIPI camera for RPi3.

He connected CAM_GPIO0 signal to INCLK of the sensor but I was wondering if it is a typical way to do it. Other boards(for example official imx219, imx477) are connecting an external OSC(e.g 32.128Mhz) to the INCLK.

Comment: Ah, let me see. External clock source, whether crystal or otherwise nowadays is so dirt cheap that there is no reason to consider a clock programmed by software, even with guarantee of any production period of say 5 years. Of course it depends on too many things, with so many engineering trade offs and business cost benefit/risk analysis etc,  and so there is no clear cut decision. Good luck. Cheers.

Comment: I see. So, that is possible. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. BTW, you asked if it is a "typical" way to use the Rpi/MCU built in clock. Actually I forgot to point out that, for the early developing stages of prototyping and feasibility study, it is flexible and efficient to use mcu built in clocks to try out different clock speeds. Perhaps during the final prototyping stage and before volume/mass production of PCB etc, then you finalize a digital quartz or analog PLL clock. Just amateur/hobbyist brainstorming comments. Have a great project. Cheers.

Comment: Good to know that. I didn't know RPi PLL output can be mapped to IO port.

Comment: Ah sorry, just a casual comment about PLL. On second thought, not likely any PLL.  My apologies.